# Trouble with django-cors-header - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'corsheaders'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I'm trying to add the Django-Cors-Headers library to my Django REST Framework project, which is Dockerized. Running my project works fine without the library but after I add it by following the documentation on the [django-cors-headers github](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/) - specifically:

Install from pip:

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

(Although in my case, since it's dockerized, I did:)

```
docker-compose run --rm web pip install django-cors-headers
```

and then add it to your installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
)
```

You will also need to add a middleware class to listen in on responses:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

Okay, so knowing all of that, I then run:

```
docker-compose up
```

Which essentially just waits for postgres, migrates, and then runs the server.

Here is my stack-trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 24, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'corsheaders'
```

I've also tried adding the django-cors-headers==2.40 to the requirements.txt and installing via:

```
docker-compose run --rm web pip install -r requirements.txt
```

but I get the same result. Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated!! This is my first time doing a project using django, drf, or docker, so apologies if I'm not the most knowledgable :)

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: @a_k_v yes I encounter the problem when I try to start the server initially.

Comment: use pip freeze and check whether it is installed?

Comment: @a_k_v okay nice, running pip freeze in my local directory (in venv) shows the django-cors-headers library, but when I run "docker-compose run --rm web pip freeze" the library is missing. So there's something I don't understand then about installing dependencies when using Docker clearly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add cores-header requirement into requirement. txt. Run the docker-compose up command from the top level directory for your project. Refer https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/#define-the-project-components.

Comment: @a_k_v I mentioned doing that in my post, right at the end. Unfortunately that doesn't do the trick either.

Comment: run docker-compose run --rm --service-ports web bash. You probably get a command line interface. There you add pip install cores-headers.

Comment: could you please share the docker-compose file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cors-header missing in you docker. So add

```
django-cors-headers
```

in your requirement.txt of your project. add the django-cors-headers dependencies to your Dockerfile after (RUN apt-get update .....).
now build and run. Using either

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

or

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Comment: This is it! I wasn't building first :|

This is clearly what happens when you use a boilerplate without extensive knowledge of the tools you're using :) 

Thank you for your help!